# Switch to Docker-based deployment of Metabase (>=v0.46) on Heroku

Tags: heroku, upgrade, metabase

Since [Metabase deprecated Heroku support](https://www.metabase.com/releases/Metabase-0.45#note-that-starting-with-this-release-metabase-045-heroku-support-is-now-deprecated) with the release of v0.45, the [metabase-deploy](https://github.com/metabase/metabase-deploy) workflow doesn't upgrade to the latest version anymore.

Going forward, it seems we need to use Docker-based deployments on Heroku, but the [Upgrading Metabase](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/installation-and-operation/upgrading-metabase) page doesn't provide any instructions on how to switch from the previous deployment method. Can anybody point us in the right direction?

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get a Metabase container running by creating the two files mentioned in this [post](https://discourse.metabase.com/t/support-for-heroku/23506/5). First I pulled down the Heroku repo for the app and then replaced the files with these ones:

Dockerfile

```
FROM metabase/metabase:v0.46.5

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /app/

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$PORT" ]; then
    export MB_JETTY_PORT="$PORT"
fi

if [ "$DATABASE_URL" ]; then
    export MB_DB_CONNECTION_URI="$DATABASE_URL"
fi

# We need to override the $JAVA_OPTS and give it a slightly lower memory limit
# because Heroku tends to think we can use more memory than we actually can.
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions"
JAVA_OPTS+=" -XX:+UseContainerSupport"         # Tell the JVM to use container info to set heap limit -- see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues#configuring-java-to-run-in-a-container
JAVA_OPTS+=" -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit"          # Disable limit to amount of time spent in GC. Better slow than not working at all
JAVA_OPTS+=" -XX:+UseCompressedOops"           # Use 32-bit pointers. Reduces memory usage
JAVA_OPTS+=" -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers"  # Same as above. See also http://blog.leneghan.com/2012/03/reducing-java-memory-usage-and-garbage.html
JAVA_OPTS+=" -Xverify:none"                    # Skip bytecode verification, the Heroku buildpack comes from us so it's already verified. Speed up launch slightly
JAVA_OPTS+=" -XX:+UseG1GC"                     # G1GC seems to use slightly less memory in my testing...
JAVA_OPTS+=" -XX:+UseStringDeduplication"      # Especially when used in combination with string deduplication

# Other Java options
JAVA_OPTS+=" -server"                  # Run in server mode. This is the default for 64-bit JVM
JAVA_OPTS+=" -Djava.awt.headless=true" # don't try to start AWT. Not sure this does anything but better safe than wasting memory
JAVA_OPTS+=" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"    # Use UTF-8

# Set timezone using the JAVA_TIMEZONE variable if present
if [ "$JAVA_TIMEZONE"]; then
    echo "  -> Timezone setting detected: $JAVA_TIMEZONE"
    JAVA_OPTS+=" -Duser.timezone=$JAVA_TIMEZONE"
fi

echo "JAVA_OPTS: $JAVA_OPTS"
export JAVA_OPTS

/app/run_metabase.sh
```

I backed up the database and then ran these commands:

```
heroku container:login
heroku container:push web
heroku container:release web
```

Make sure there is a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable set. I needed to have Metabase run on less than 1GB of RAM so I also set a `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable with this value `-Xms640m -Xmx640m`